# Windows batch command to logout a specific User

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to write a batch-script that logs off a specific user, which is connected via remotedesktop to a Windows Server 2016.
On Linux i can just write pkill -u "Username" and now i am looking for an altanative on Windows.

I need to close the Session from the User so I can delete him. 
I have tried to remove the user from the remote desktop user group but this does not close the current session.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This should be of interest to Disconnect-LoggedOnUser. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Disconnect-LoggedOnUser-116ea40c

Comment: Are you sure you need a batch script for this?  I seem to recall that server has a GUI for viewing and managing connected users.  In, fact, there's a tab in Task Manager for that as well.

Comment: I develop a Server with dynamic users for our school. This Server is used for exams and the idea is that the User-Accounts are created just before the exam starts and are deleted after the exam is over. I have already written a script which creates the users dynamically for every exam, but when i delete them with my script they are still logged in and i want them to lose the session.